Linear mixed models with and without interactions
Here is the context: I asked two types of questions 8 times (8 "sessions" with 2 questions, each question has a "number" i.e. whether it is the first or second question asked, and a "type" i.e. whether it is type 1 or type 2 question) to 11 "people". I recorded whether people gave correct responses ("accuracy") and their response time ("time"). I am interested at looking what factors best explain response time. So I conducted this linear mixed model:
model A: log(time) ~ accuracy + session + question_number + question_type + (1|people) (with lmer on R)
Because I wanted to know whether adding an interaction term would improve the model, I conducted six more models, each of these models being model A with an additional interaction. For three of these models, I get this message in R "fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 1 column / coefficient" but no problem for comparing two of them to model 1.
The problem is only for the third one (model B: log(time) ~ accuracy + session + question_number + question_type + question_numer:question_type + (1|people)): I get strange results when I compare it to model 1. anova(modelA,modelB) returns Chisq=0, Df=0 and no p-value.
Moreover, anova(modelB) returns nothing (no F-value, no p-value, etc.) for the interaction term question_number:question_type.
Do you know the problem could come from ? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.
